# Deep pick all nested data props

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I am sending this data to my action for an api post. Is there a way I can use lodash to grab all the props and put them into the top level?

```
rangeStartYear:12
Id:3647074,
updatedElements:{
    testgroup:"asasa",
    testAgain: "yep"
},
anotherValue: 111,
data:{
    value1:"asasa", 
    value2: "yep"
}
```

I'm currently using if statements to check to data:

```
 var rowDataToSave = {};

    if(addUpdateData.updatedElements) {
        rowDataToSave = addUpdateData.updatedElements;
    }

    if(addUpdateData.data){
        rowDataToSave = addUpdateData.data;
        if(addUpdateData.data.row){
            rowDataToSave = addUpdateData.data.row;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: would it be possible to pull all the data above into something like this:

```
data:{
    testgroup:"asasa",
    testAgain: "yep",
    value1:"asasa", 
    value2: "yep",
    anotherValue: 111,
    rangeStartYear:12
    Id:3647074,
 }
```

Can I improve this using lodash?

Comment: Not sure I follow this, Can you give a more detailed example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining properly, updated my post